# How do Lists hold object references/vales in Java?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

When I add an object to a List and change the object's property, that change will propagate to the object in the list, however when I set the object to null, I do not get a null pointer from the object in the list. Why is this?

```
public class Hworld {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        List<Obj> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Hworld.Obj o = new Obj();

        list.add(o);

        for(Obj ob:list) {
            System.out.println(ob.b); // prints "base"
        }

        o.b="new";
        o=null;

        for(Obj ob:list) {
            System.out.println(ob.b); // prints "new"
        }

    }

    public static class Obj{

        String b = "base";

    }   
}
```

Comment: A variable is just a holder for a reference. When you set `o` equal to `null`, the object still exists, you have just erased that particular reference to it. The list still holds its own reference. When all references to a given object are lost, it is eligible for garbage collection and will eventually be destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because java uses **references**. When you created the object **o**, a new object created in the heap and **o** now points to that location, or **o** **refers** to the address of the newly created object. Now you have added the object **o** to the list, so the list has a reference to the same location (lets call it location for the time being). Now you did a **dot** **.** operation to the reference **o**, which actually changes the value of the member variable in the object. And now you made the **reference** **o** to point to nowhere or simply you set the reference as **null**. But the **reference** to the same location exists in the list, you haven't changed that reference. So you won't be getting any NPE and you will get the value changed earlier using the **dot(.)** operator.
Hope I have thrown some light.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the false impression null would "wipe" an object to the effect of declaring Hworld.Obj o; without instantiation

Answer (score 1):

You create an object named o. You then put this one into the list, which means, the list stores the reference to the object currently stored in o. The print result within the loop is base, because there is only one object, which has "base" stored in b.

You then modify o, setting o's b to "new". As o and the object stored in the list are the same, the modification of o also results in a change of the object stored in the list. These are the same objects.

You then set o to null. This means, o now points to null, whereas the object stored in the list points to the object originally stored in o.

Originally o points to A, you add o to the list, so the list knows about A, not o. If you then modify A using o, you can access this change using o's way to A and the list's way to A. You then set o to know about B, the list still knows about A, but nothing about B, because the list stores A, not B. o only was the transmitter to get the knowledge about A into the list.